# keras define a trainable variable for add or matmul

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have some problems in use tf.keras to build model. Now I want to define a trainbale weight tensor with shape(64, 128), which similar to tf.get_variable. However I can't achieve it.

In the past, I have try many methods.But I want to look for easily method.

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input((128,))
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((64, 128)))
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.matmul(x, tf.transpose(weights)))(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output)
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)            (None, 64)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The defined weights is not trainable.
In addition, I know Dense can get trained matrix weights and bias. But if I want add a bias, I can't use Dense.
However, I have to use add_weights in custome layer, for example:

```
class Bias(keras.layers.Layer):
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(64, 128), initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs + self.bias

inputs = Input(shape=(64, 128))
outputs = Bias()(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)        (None, 64, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
bias_5 (Bias)                (None, 64, 128)           8192      
=================================================================
Total params: 8,192
Trainable params: 8,192
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Is there any more easily method to define a trainable variable ？

Comment: The recommended way to add any trainable variable is through a layer. If there is no existing layer that does what you want then you need to define a custom layer. Defining a custom layer is something that makes sense if you are a researcher and are trying to come up with new DNN architectures; probably not the way to go if you are a practitioner and trying to simply solve an engineering problem.

Comment: It's feel inconvenient in custom layer to add trainable variable.In tensorflow, just define tf.Variable() or tf.get_variable() can easy achieve.

Comment: The goal of keras is to abstract away the need to think in terms of specific variables. Instead it lets you think in terms of layers and/or models. Whether this is good / bad depends on what you are trying to achieve. For my use case, I tend to want to reuse and adapt well know model architectures. So I want to start with a well know model (preferably pretrained) and do a small adaptation to fit my problem; I find that Keras lets me think about model architectures without having to think about variables.